# How to add a new line using for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2

I have a simple array of alphabets I use a for loop to display the alphabets on the screen I want to add every sixth letter to a new line I want to achieve this result

[image]

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        alphabet: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in alphabet" :key="index">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: Looking at your code sample, what is `i` and `name`. It doesn't look like these will be defined, so your `<br>` will never display

Comment: The accepted answer is clean, but you had edited your question from using ```<br>``` to using ```<li>```.  I came up with a ```<li>``` based solution that is requires more complexity, but since you already accepted an answer, you can go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
 export default {
   data() {
  return {
    alphabet: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
  }
 }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="(item, index) in alphabet" :key="index">
      {{ item }} <br v-if="(index + 1) % 6 == 0" />
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

you can try this, it would add a *br* after every 6 letters, and then you can add whatever styling you want to make it look like the matrix you mentioned above

Answer (score 5):

I would use here simple css by displaying this array and the button in grid.

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table__item" v-for="(item, index) in alphabet" :key="index">
      {{ item }}
  </div>
  <div class="table__button">button</div>
</div>
```

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 20px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 20px);
}

.table__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.table__button {
  grid-column: 4 / 6;
  grid-row: 5;
  background: red;
}
```